# SELECT from two (different) Excel files .NET

Tags: .net, excel, oledb

Can anyone help me with this please.
I want to do something like this.

```
strSQL = SELECT  [filename1].[" & xlSheet.Name & "$].Col1
, [filename1].[" & xlSheet.Name & "$].Col2
FROM [filename1].[" & xlSheet.Name & "$]
UNION ALL
SELECT [filename2].[" & xlSheet2.Name & "$].Col1
, [filename2].[" & xlSheet2.Name & "$].Col2
FROM  [Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename2+ ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes].[" & xlSheet2.Name & "$]
WHERE [filename1].[" & xlSheet.Name & "$].Col1= [filename2].[" & xlSheet2.Name & "$].Col1

Using conExcel As New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
conExcel.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename1 + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"
conExcel.Open()
cmdSelect.CommandText = strSQL
cmdSelect.Connection = conExcel
intRowsCount = cmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I've edit the "code" to something more similar.
The error is a OleDbException "Syntax error in FROM Clause."

Comment: I think you would be better off running each individually and dumping the results to a datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot address two different files with the one OleDb connection. You'll need to create another connection for the second file and pull the data in that way.

Here's how I usually code a method to retrieve all data from a sheet:

```
private DataTable RetrieveData(string filename, string sheetName)
{
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\"";
    string query = "SELECT * from [" + sheetName + "$]";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
        {
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        }

        conn.Close();
    }

    return dt;
}
```

And then you can just call it with each of your files:

```
DataTable dt1 = RetrieveData("filename1.xlsx", "Sheet1");
DataTable dt2 = RetrieveData("filename2.xlsx", "Sheet1");
```

Comment: It **is** possible to join two external Excel files (see my answer), but using a datatable is certainly simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use the provider syntax for OleDb inside an OleDb query. The syntax for connecting to an external Excel file inside a query is different.

Also, SQL doesn't have a notion of files, only of tables; you can't refer to the field in a particular file by its filename (e.g. `filename1`, `filename2`). However, you can define the second file in your UNION's FROM clause as a second table.

```
var strSQL = String.Format(@"
    SELECT [{0}$].Col1,
        [{0}$].Col2,
    FROM [{0}$]

    UNION ALL
    SELECT [{1}$].Col1,
        [{1}$].Col1
    FROM [{1}$] IN ""{2}"" ""Excel 12.0;""

    WHERE [{0}$].Col1 = [{1}$].Col1
", xlSheet.Name, xlSheet2.Name, @"C:\path\to\exce\file");
```

If you are trying to `JOIN` the tables, use a `JOIN` instead of a `UNION`+`WHERE`.

Links:

- [IN Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177907%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [INNER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware you could do that.